# Why isn't the debugger working in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, cython

The accelerated cython debugger in pycharm does not work when debugging a multi-threaded application. Could this be due to the fact that I have problems in the implementation of the code? Or does such a debugger fail with multithreading?

Comment: Please detail "does not work". What do you expect ? What do you have ? What do you want ?

Comment: I have a multithreaded application that needs to be debugged and it does not work with the cython accelerated debugger

Comment: You already said that. Nobody can help you if you do not provide more information. What's happening when you start your debug ? Is there some error code ? What did you already tried ? Are you able to debug with single thread ? Please edit your question.

Comment: I put a point and the debugger does not reach it, but hangs somewhere. This happens even in one stream

Comment: Then its not a multithread problem and you answered to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

> Could this be due to the fact that I have problems in the implementation of the code?

Yes, it could, and certainly be.

> does such a debugger fail with multithreading ?

It seems not to be documented anywhere, and as discussed in comments it also fail with single thread so your problem is probably somewhere else.

I suggest to try with very simple threads first, like just one `print('foo')` and the other `print('bar')` and observe what is happening.